# networking.service ExecStartPre= (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: networking

I have a question, why ExecStartPre= has a FAILURE status in this case?, because everything seems fine and working. Could somebody explain what is going on?

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-04-03 05:04:52 MSK; 3min 54s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 473 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 467 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 473 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 36864)
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service

апр 03 05:04:52 debian systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
апр 03 05:04:52 debian systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:303  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:01:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9032  bytes 6039361 (5.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6961  bytes 915411 (893.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 114  bytes 34267 (33.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 114  bytes 34267 (33.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just means that this command exited with status 1:

```
/bin/sh -c '[ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle'
```

It might have exited with status 1 if:

- `CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=no` is set (in your /etc/default/networking); or
- `ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo` returns empty; or
- `udevadm settle` exits 1

The first two are not really errors per-se... They're there mostly to help decide when `udevadm settle` needs to be run... So, in a way, you could consider that that ExecStartPre failing with status=1 might be "normal" in a certain way.

Checking on my systems, I have one where the `ifquery` command returns empty output, so that's most likely the explanation for the status=1.

I guess Debian could have made this a bit nicer, by using an `if` instead of `&&`, since in that case if the condition isn't true, the command doesn't exit with status 1, but 0:

```
/bin/sh -c 'if [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ]; then udevadm settle; fi'
```

Comment: https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/ifupdown.git/commit/debian/networking.service?id=4b01a3943d105a9870f32926e49bc6b3cc7c3fb5  You should suggest this. Although I suspect that this behaviour is actually the intended one.

Comment: @JdeBP good call! Done: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=894759